# CHARINDEX is returning 0 even when the substring is present

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to extract a substring of one of the column.

```
SELECT PT.col1 AS MyColumn
    ,(
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(PT.col1, '$') > 0
             THEN SUBSTRING(PT.col1, CHARINDEX(PT.col1, '$') + 1, 
                  LEN(PT.col1) - CHARINDEX(PT.col1, '$') - 1)
             ELSE ''
        END 
     )
,T1.col2
,PT.col3
,T1.col4
,T1.col5
 //...
```

All I'm getting is empty string for all the rows. I've tried just to display the index of the `$' character but I'm getting`0`.

The value of `PT.col1` looks like `French (Canada)$fr-CA`, `Portuguese (Brazil)$pt-BR`, ...

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  have to switch the parameters:

```
SELECT CHARINDEX('a$bc', '$') AS Wrong, CHARINDEX('$', 'a$bc') AS Ok
/*
Wrong       Ok
----------- -----------
0           2
*/
```